Arch Linux: GDM is defaulting to X11 instead of Wayland. What's up with my configuration?
I was under the impression that my Arch Linux box was running on Wayland, given that GDM supposedly defaults to it. However, after checking XDG_SESSION_TYPE this morning, it seems that I've been on X11. This agrees with the listed session type in loginctl.
I have followed various guides to get my configuration right (in particular, the Arch Wiki), but GDM keeps choosing X11.
I have an Nvidia Geforce 1050 Ti, with the Arch nvidia driver installed, with stock GNOME (so my WM is Mutter).
My /etc/environment is below:
GBM_BACKEND=nvidia-drm
__GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia

Below is the output of systemctl status gdm.service, none of the usual errors that would cause GDM to choose X11 seem to be logged.
Jul 10 12:07:48 … gdm-password][966]: pam_systemd_home(gdm-password:auth): New sd-bus connection (system-bus-pam-systemd-home-966) opened.
Jul 10 12:07:52 … gdm-password][985]: pam_ecryptfs: Passphrase file wrapped
Jul 10 12:07:53 … gdm-password][966]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Jul 10 12:07:53 … gdm-password][966]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Jul 10 12:07:53 … gdm-password][966]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user willow(uid=1000) by willow(uid=0)
Jul 10 12:07:53 … gdm-password][966]: pam_systemd(gdm-password:session): New sd-bus connection (system-bus-pam-systemd-966) opened.
Jul 10 12:07:53 … gdm-password][966]: gkr-pam: the password for the login keyring was invalid.
Jul 10 12:07:54 … gdm[568]: Gdm: on_display_added: assertion 'GDM_IS_REMOTE_DISPLAY (display)' failed
Jul 10 12:07:57 … gdm[568]: Gdm: Child process -630 was already dead.
Jul 10 12:07:57 … gdm[568]: Gdm: on_display_removed: assertion 'GDM_IS_REMOTE_DISPLAY (display)' failed

When I first posted this question, I thought I had identified the root of the problem. I had discovered that nvidia_drm.modeset was somehow not being enabled, in spite of kms and nvidia_modeset both being in the right places of my mkinitcpio.conf:
MODULES=(nvidia nvidia_modeset nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm)
…
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf kms keyboard keymap consolefont block filesystems fsck)

I also had (and still have) a modprobe configuration file at /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia_drm_modeset.conf:
options nvidia_drm modeset=1

Checking the value of /sys/module/nvidia_drm/parameters/modeset reveals that it was stubbornly N rather than Y as expected. After enabling nvidia-hibernate.service, nvidia-suspend.service, and nvidia-resume.service as described in Ren's answer, this parameter is now Y, but the problem persists.
There doesn't even seem to be a way to select X11 or Wayland on the login screen.
What on earth is going on with my system?

Please enable the following services via systemd:
nvidia-hibernate.service, nvidia-suspend.service & nvidia-resume.service and reboot. Arch Linux should use Wayland by default then.

This solution was, unfortunately, ineffective. XDG_SESSION_TYPE is still x11.

However, the nvidia-drm.modeset parameter is now Y. The plot thickens...

You can follow this then https://wiki.hyprland.org/Nvidia it works for me always.

Isn't that literally just setting the value of XDG_SESSION_TYPE, not what protocol is actually being used? I've been having trouble finding the documentation for what these environment variables are actually doing…

Please reboot, and then upon logging back in - logout and then choose "gnome" session instead of "gnome x11". Maybe your setup still follows x11 instead of wayland.

There is no menu to select a session type on the login screen, to my knowledge.

have you logged out properly? If done properly, you should be able to see a cog icon at the bottom right when u choose the account u want to login in the login screen. It will have all the environments like gnome, gnome with x11, etc.

I am rebooting Arch Linux and it simply isn't there. There is a cog in the bottom right when I am prompted to enter a password, but it does not appear to be for specifying a window system. It specifies "Gnome", "Gnome (Classic)", or "Kodi".

I discovered an additional troubleshooting step after finding some posts on the Arch Linux forum. I managed to work around the problem by overriding GDM's default udev rules, which I believe were causing GDM to disable Wayland functionality, by creating a symbolic link to /dev/null at /etc/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules. To the best of my knowledge, this completely removes the checks that would cause GDM to disable Wayland.
My GNOME sessions now have the option to run under either X11 or Wayland, as Ren implies should be the case.
I will investigate further, with more nuanced udev overrides, until I pin down the exact cause of the issue.
